# Craft CMS - Audio file won't play using resourceUrl inside plugin

Tags: html, audio, craftcms

Essentially I'm moving a static HTML site into Craft. I've created a new plugin for the site and have gotten a good chunk of it working however I'm having an issue where audio files won't play. The site is supposed to have music auto-playing and looping (it's a site for kids before you start judging me, haha), and it works correcrtly on the static site, however nothing plays in my Craft instance and when I go to the direct URL for the audio file it won't play in browser either but doesn't give me a 404. If I "Save As" it does then download correctly.

Code is very simple:

```
<audio autoplay loop>
        <source src="{{ resourceUrl('somesite/audio/some_theme_full.ogg') }}" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="{{ resourceUrl('somesite/audio/some_theme_full.mp3') }}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

The src generates correctly as e.g http://site.local/cpresources/somesite/audio/some_theme_full.mp3?d=1513706441.

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same browser to visit the existing site and to develop with? Try incognito mode on the original site.

> …web browsers are moving towards stricter autoplay policies in order to improve the user experience, minimize incentives to install ad blockers, and reduce data consumption on expensive and/or constrained networks.

More here on Google's recent [autoplay policy changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).